# Should we still develop for MSIE7?

Tags: internet-explorer, browser

I've doing a lot of research and found an average of what web browser are being used. All results seem to differ from about 10%. The results I found are:

Gecko-based: 30%
Webkit/Khtml: 22%
presto: 3%
MSIE6: 5%
MSIE7: 7%
MSIE8+: 27%
Other: 6%

From what this shows, should we still develop for MSIE7? I've stopped developing for MSIE6 for a while now but should we stop for MSIE7. Those who have updated to MSIE7, many have also updated to MSIE8/9.

So the question is:

If MSIE7 only has 7% market share, should we still develop for MSIE7?

Comment: I'd say that depends on your website's target audience.

Comment: Better question: should we still develop for MSIE anyway?

Comment: well WTP, that is a good question. Chrome has the best acid score and also supports the most css3 and html5 features also firefox does, but what is with ie?

Comment: @Daniel Ruf: I can't wait till all website say to IE users: "You are using an unsupported browser." And, if M$ likes to torture web developers, why won't web developers simply ignore M$ and stop spilling their time? :)

Comment: hm, is a really good question, thanks to the css3 box-sizing we fixed some problems in our agency with the mostly hated box model. On my mac at work i can just test in the safari chrome and firefox, testing with ie is a gruel. Its a signg that ms lets choose the user which browser the user wants to be installed instead of ie

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I think you should let users know that they are using an older browser and should upgrade soon - I wouldn't prevent them from using the site however, but give them very obvious warnings that things might not work correctly.

Also, have you seen this:

> For this reason, soon Google Apps will only support modern browsers. Beginning August 1st, we’ll support the current and prior major release of Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer and Safari on a rolling basis. Each time a new version is released, we’ll begin supporting the update and stop supporting the third-oldest version.
>
> As of August 1st, we will discontinue
>   support for the following browsers and
>   their predecessors: Firefox 3.5,
>   Internet Explorer 7, and Safari 3. In
>   these older browsers you may have
>   trouble using certain features in
>   Gmail, Google Calendar, Google Talk,
>   Google Docs and Google Sites, and
>   eventually these apps may stop working
>   entirely.

[Google announcement](https://drive.googleblog.com/2011/06/our-plans-to-support-modern-browsers.html)

Google is going to stop supporting older browsers - the more websites that jump on this bandwagon, the better for everyone.

Comment: This seems to the best approach to it thank you. However, do you think the announcement should prevent the usage of the website or just be shown on it?

Comment: For a public facing website, unless you know for a fact that they are going to have serious problems or errors using your site with the 'wrong' browser, I would still let them in with the warning to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should, also 7% is a lot. http://marketshare.hitslink.com/browser-market-share.aspx?spider=1&qprid=2

The question should be more: should we suppoer ie6?

in our agency we still support ie6 (some png fixes etc) and test each project in every browser

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on what is your target. For example, if you are targeting a web developer group with your site, I would say quit building for IE7.

Also, this would be legit for young group target. They are most likely to use cutting-edge browsers than the older ones.

But as it is suggested before for every possible scenario, that  would be nice to inform users they are using out of date browser. Here is an example. There is a web site called http://www.ie6countdown.com/ and they encourage everyone to support the death of IE6 by putting a simple banner code into the body of your website;

http://www.theie6countdown.com/join-us.aspx

Lastly, there are some javascript libraries which will make your life easier. For example, you can build on HTML5 today and run it on IE6 if you could reference a JavaScript library called [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/)